# É possível fazer o javascript esperar um dado async do android?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

Imaginem esse cenário: tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em angularjs que roda em alguns ambientes como hardware proprietário e computadores. Atualmente estamos adicionando nosso software para a plataforma android e estamos tendo alguns problemas.

Nossa aplicação em Angular é desenvolvida toda fazendo chamadas HTTP, ou seja, o ambiente que estamos rodando o app (sim, ela roda em localhost) só precisa ter nosso webservice rodando.

No android, a gente conseguiu criar um webservice só que com diversos problemas como:

• Em alguns devices, depois que a memoria ultrapassa 50mb ou 75mb, o aplicativo é fechado.

• Caso o aplicativo esteja rodando num service (que é nosso caso), ele só pode ser reiniciado depois de crachar num intervalo grande de tempo, caso contrario, o SO Android não reinicia o service.

• Um aplicativo não foi feito pra ser um servidor http (em teoria, rs)

Devido a esses problemas e alguns outros, tentamos adotar outra solução que é o uso do [JavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html). Com ele é possível chamar métodos do android via javascript (acredito que IONIC e companhia use algo parecido com isso).

Então eis a minha tentativa de gambiarra: A fim de não ter milhões de IFS nos meus services dizendo quem eu quero chamar, tentei criar um interceptor no angular, só que tive alguns problemas..

Se no meu método android eu tiver uma chamada assync, é possível fazer o javascript esperar para retornar?

A ideia do interceptor é toda chamada HTTP cair no método **responseError**, já que o webservice não existe, e quando entrar no responseError, fazer a chamada para o android, algo desse jeito:

```
app.factory('httpInterceptor', function($q){
    return {
        'responseError': function(config) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(window.PFL.getSmfFile());
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
})
```

E no meu android, eu tenho isso:

```
    package myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterfaceManager(this), "PFL");
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/interceptors.html");
    }

    public class JSInterfaceManager {

        String result = "Empty";
        Activity activity;

        public JSInterfaceManager(Activity context) {
            this.activity = context;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public String getSmfFile() throws InterruptedException {

            getData(new DataCallBack() {
                @Override
                public void onSucess(String data) {
                    result = "DEU CERTO";
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "oi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(VolleyError error) {
                    result = "DEU ERRO";
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "oi error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


            return result;
        }

        private void getData(final DataCallBack callBack) {
            String URL = "someLink";
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    callBack.onSucess(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    callBack.onError(error);
                }
            });
            HTTP.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        }

    }


}

public class HTTP extends Application {

    private static final String TAG = HTTP.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static HTTP mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized HTTP getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }

}
```

Essa abordagem usando Volley foi uma tentativa de retornar a chamada em modo sinchrono (vi isso num blog e tentei implementar).

A minha dúvida é: **como consigo fazer uma chamada http pelo android e retornar na chamada http do angular. É possível? Existem outros meios?**

Desculpa pela pergunta gigante

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem a sua pergunta, mas se realmente é só fazer a requisição no Android e quando terminar retornar para o Javascript, por que você não cria um plugin para o Cordova que vai ser só a ponte entre o JS e o nativo? 

Com isso, você pode rodar o código no Android, fazer o que tem que fazer e quando terminar, chamar o callback lá do Angular.

Comment: @Paulo, somente para tentar entender sua necessidade. Você vai fazer uma requisição do Android para o servidor Node, o servidor vai receber essa chamada e depois fazer outra chamada para um dispositivo Android é isso ?